# How to join data frames in R without duplicating original data values

Tags: r, join, row-number

I have 2 data frames (`DF1` & `DF2`) and 1 would like to join them together by a unique value called `"acc_num"`. In `DF2`, payment was made twice by acc_num `A` and thrice by `B`. Data frames are as follows.

DF1:

```
 acc_num     total_use    sales
    A           433        145
    A            NA          2
    A            NA         18
    B           149         32
```

DF2:

```
   acc       payment   
    A           150
    A            98
    B            44
    B            15
    B            10
```

My desired output is:

```
 acc_num    total_use    sales    payment
    A            433       145       150
    A             NA         2        98
    A             NA        18        NA
    B            149        32        44
    B             NA        NA        15
    B             NA        NA        10
```

I've tried `full_join` and `merge` but the output was not as desired. I couldn't work this out as I'm still a beginner in R, and haven't found the solution to this.

Example of the code I used was

```
test_full_join <- DF1 %>% full_join(DF2, by = c("acc_num" = "acc"))
```

The displayed output was:

```
 acc_num       total_use   sales     payment
    A             433       145        150
    A             433       145         98
    A              NA         2        150
    A              NA         2         98
    A              NA        18        150
    A              NA        18         98
    B             149        32         44
    B             149        32         15
    B             149        32         10
```

This is contrary to my desired output as at the end, 
my concern is to get the total sum of `total_use`, `sales` and `payment`. 
This output will definitely give me wrong interpretation 
for data visualization later on.

Comment: Both the dataset have duplicates for 'acc_num'

Comment: Sum all wanted columns by `acc_num` first (ie, make one record per `acc_num` element) and merge then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need to do a join by `row_number()` based on 'acc_num'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(acc_num) %>%
     mutate(grpind = row_number()) %>% 
     full_join(df2 %>% 
                   group_by(acc_num = acc) %>%
                   mutate(grpind = row_number())) %>%
     select(acc_num, total_use, sales, payment)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   acc_num [2]
#  acc_num total_use sales payment
#  <chr>       <int> <int>   <int>
#1 A             433   145     150
#2 A              NA     2      98
#3 A              NA    18      NA
#4 B             149    32      44
#5 B              NA    NA      15
#6 B              NA    NA      10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(acc_num = c("A", "A", "A", "B"), total_use = c(433L, 
NA, NA, 149L), sales = c(145L, 2L, 18L, 32L)), class = "data.frame",
   row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(acc = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), payment = c(150L, 
98L, 44L, 15L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```